# Accessing security system settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How would you access the security system settings eg airplane mode.. from android studio. I can do it through  adb but I'd prefer to do it through android studio in my application. I tried writing code that gives the user an option to select 'modify system settings options' to give full access but it still keeps telling `Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`, most of the answers are a bit old so it would be nice if someone directed me to a path

Comment: Could you shae some of this code so people can review it and maybe point out a better way to help you?

Answer (score 0):

All permissions that your app wants to use (INTERNET,BLUETOOTH, etc) must be defined on the Manifest.XML file like this:

`<uses-permission android:name="permission here"/>`

Spesifically the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission's protection level is "signature" (more on that [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element)) and that means that permission is only granted to systems apps. So to "fix" your Permission denial error you need to add this permission into the Manifest.XML file, but this is redundant because it wont let you USE that permission due to its protection level.

Comment: Yeah i know how to access the normal settings from manifest but from your last statement how would i use the permission because adding security permission settings from manifest is useless

Comment: You are not able to use any permission with 'signature' protection level, so all permissions defined in the Android's API and having such protection level are unavailable to 3rd party apps.